# Unable to find MyModule.gwt.xml compiling a GWT project with Ant

Tags: java, gwt, ant

I have an error with this ant script :

```
<path id="gwt-client.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.gwt.xml" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${gwt.client.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${gwt.shared.dir}" />
</path>

<path id="gwt-sdk.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${gwt.sdk.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="gwt-compile" depends="prepareResources">
    <property name="clientClasspath" refid="gwt-client.classpath" />
    <echo message="==> gwt-client classpath = ${clientClasspath}" />
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="gwt-sdk.classpath" />
            <path refid="gwt-client.classpath" />
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M" />
        <arg line="${gwt.module.name} -logLevel INFO  -style PRETTY" />
    </java>
</target>
```

While the console tells me great things :

```
[echo] ==> gwt-client classpath = 
  C:\code\repository\comments\src\io\robusta\fora\comments\Comments.gwt.xml;
  C:\code\repository\comments\src\io\robusta\fora\comments\client;
  C:\code\repository\comments\src\io\robusta\fora\comments\shared
```

All these files exist, but I have the very classic error :

```
[java] Loading inherited module 'io.robusta.fora.comments.Comments'
     [java]    [ERROR] Unable to find 'io/robusta/fora/comments/Comments.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

I tend to think that I missuse the Ant terminology between path, pathelement, refid ... Or that the error message should look for `src/io/robusta/fora/comments/Comments.gwt.xml` instead of `io/robusta/fora/comments/Comments.gwt.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the *classpath* works. Each *path element* in the classpath is a *root* against which fully-qualified names (package + class name) are resolved. Those paths can be either folders or archives (ZIPs or JARs).

Classes in the `io.robusta.fora.comments.client` package live (in your case) in the `C:\core\repository\comments\src` folder. This is what should be in the classpath.

Same for resources: `io/robusta/fora/comments/Comments.gwt.xml` is looked up in the classpath, so, in your case, `C:\core\repository\comments\src` should be in the classpath so that the relative path can be correctly resolved to the file.